# How to place floats after a section heading and how to place it before one?

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Is there a latex command that can be used to force floats to be positioned AFTER a specified section heading? And correspondingly, how to force floats to be positioned BEFORE a section heading?

Comment: I have to agree with @lockstep , I believe that this your specific case is covered by the question he links to.

Comment: Anyway, as a side note: floats are not designed to be forced into a precisely defined position. They aren1t called *floats* for nothing...

Comment: Thanks, I followed the path offered by "lockstep" and found what I needet : )